# How to Dynamically Refresh ListFragment when Item is Deleted while Using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

So I am trying to refresh a list fragment when an item is deleted. The way I have it right now restarts the loader which causes a stutter in the UI when the loader is actually restarting.

I am restarting the loader in the `listViewLongClick()` method.

Here is my code for the adapter and list fragment:

```
public class EntriesListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entries_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initButton();

        fillData();

        listViewLongClick()
    }

    private void listViewLongClick() { assignmentsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, int i, long l) {
        String entryId = ((TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.assignment_id)).getText().toString();
        Uri uri = ElicitContract.Assignments.buildAssignmentIdUri(assignmentId);
        mContentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, AssignmentsListFragment.this);
        fillData();
        return true;
        });
    } 

    private void fillData() {
        String[] from = new String[]{EntriesContract.EntriesColumns.ENTRIES_TITLE, EntriesContract.EntriesColumns.ENTRIES_DETAIL};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.entries_title, R.id.entries_description};

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_entries, null, from, to, 0);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {EntriesContract.EntriesColumns.ENTRIES_ID, EntriesContract.EntriesColumns.ENTRIES_TITLE, EntriesContract.EntriesColumns.ENTRIES_DETAIL};

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), EntriesContract.ENTRIES_BASE_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fillData();
    }
}
```

Here is my content provider code:

```
public class ElicitProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String TAG = ElicitProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    private EntriesDatabase entriesDatabase; // Get a copy of the database.

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    private static final int ENTRIES = 1;
    private static final int ENTRIES_ID = 2;

    private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = EntriesContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

        matcher.addURI(authority, "entries", ENTRIES);
        matcher.addURI(authority, "entries/*", ENTRIES_ID);

        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        entriesDatabase = new EntriesDatabase(getContext()); // Creating a new instance of the Elicit Database.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match) {
            case ENTRIES:
                return EntriesContract.Entries.CONTENT_ENTRIES_TYPE;
            case ENTRIES_ID:
                return EntriesContract.Entries.CONTENT_ENTRIES_ITEM_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = entriesDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(EntriesContract.ENTRIES_PATH);

        switch (match) {
            case ENTRIES:
                break;
            case ENTRIES_ID:
                String id = EntriesContract.Entries.getEntryId(uri);
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = entriesDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        long recordId;

        switch (match) {
            case ENTRIES:
                recordId = db.insertOrThrox(EntriesDatabase.Tables.ENTRIES, null, contentValues);
                return EntriesContract.Entxies.buildentryIdUri(String.valueOf(recordId));
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentEception("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        if (uri.equals(EntriesContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI)) {
            deleteDatabase();x
            return 0;
        }

        final SQLiteDatabase db = entriesDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match) {
            case ENTRIES_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                String selectionCriteria = BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ")" : "");
                return db.delete(EntriesDatabase.Tables.ENTRIES, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = entriesDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        String selectionCriteria = selection;

        switch (match) {
            case ENTRIES:
                break;
            case ENTRIES_ID:
                String id = EntriesContract.Entries.getentryId(uri);
                selectionCriteria = BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ")" : "");
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }

        int updateCount = db.update(EntriesDatabase.Tables.ENTRIES, contentValues, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs);
        return updateCount;
    }

    // Delete the instance of the database and create a new one
    public void deleteDatabase() {
        entriesDatabase.close();
        EntriesDatabase.deleteDatabase(getContext());
        entriesDatabase = new EntriesDatabase(getContext());
    }
}
```

I am also thinking that this is not the most efficient method of refreshing a list fragment.

I took a look at other similar issues and they said to use entriesListView.`notifyDataSetChanged()` but I don't know where to put it and how to use it because if I replace this line with `getLoaderManager()`.restartLoader then it gives me a **null pointer error**.

To summarize, my question is how would I dynamically refresh a `listFragment` without restarting the loader which I think is less efficient and causes a stutter in the UI.

Thank you to everyone in advance for helping me out!

Comment: what does your ContentProvider look like?

Comment: @pskink I will update my post with that code.

Comment: see http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/, the section **"Notifying listeners of dataset changes"**  amd **"Updating and deleting records of your content provider"** in particular

Comment: @pskink That seems to be working now as I have added the notifyChange () code. The problem is that it is still causing a stutter in the ListView. Is that not avoidable? By the way if you post this as an answer, I can accept it as a solution. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: i dont know since i have no idea what you do now when deleting the item

Comment: @pskink Well, all I did was update my content provider with notifyChange(), just like the link that you gave me.

Comment: in `onItemLongClick` remove getLoaderManager().restartLoader() and fillData() all you need is just to mContentResolver.delete()